# Troubleshooting a broken speaker system

Tags: amplifier, troubleshooting

First I apologize if this is the wrong place for this question.

Recently my sub-woofer/amplifier stopped working, and I would like to know what is broken. I opened the case and didn't find any physical damage, and was wonder how I should proceed to discover what the defect is.

I am electronics novice, but would like to use this as an opportunity to learn more. What is the general procedure in a case like this? Should I use multimeter to find where the current is blocked?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

well, to be honest you'd have to have a decent understanding of the circuit to really track down a component failure.

That being said i've fixed a few of my own internally amplifier speakers, it was almost always a solder joint that cracked or came free from its pad, probably as a result of thermal stress.

So one thing you can do is look over all the solder joints carefully and re-solder any that look like they are possibly cracked.  All you should need is a soldering iron, some flux and some solder.

EDIT: One additional common point of failure in such electronics: electrolytic capacitors.  They are used a ton in audio electronics and have limited life spans, look for any bulging or exploded cans.  They are pretty easy to replace if this is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

First checks are the obvious ones; things like the fuse and the wiring require little experience to verify. Make sure the speakers are actually okay, by testing them on another system, if possible, or by testing another set of speakers with the amp.

Then use your multimeter to test the power supply. Use it on DC volts and measure the output. A failure in the power supply will likely take out the whole amp. Be careful - mains voltages are present in some parts.

Other things to test would really come down to the exact model and specifications. Consulting the service manual, which is usually only a google away, may be very useful. Often lower end brands don't have service manuals, because they intend for the models to be replaced anyway. But higher end gear will have some.

Test equipment of at least a multimeter will be required, but a scope is invaluable, even if it's just a 10 MHz single channel model (though I'd recommend a 50-100 MHz dual channel.) A scope is a serious bit of kit and the price reflects that - around $200 is about what you'll pay for an second hand one and you can pick up a nice new 50 MHz digital storage scope for ~$400. With a scope, you can compare the reference waveforms often given in a service manual with what you see on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

In general when troubleshooting, you need to isolate the problem by proving whether parts work or don't work.  Does the power supply work if it's disconnected from anything else?  Does the preamp work if it's disconnected from the amp?  Does the speaker work if connected to another amplifier?

Do you have only a multimeter?  A scope would be more useful.  With a meter you can still test for signal by measuring AC voltage, though.

Answer (score 1):

You state that your "subwoofer/amplifier" is not working.

Typically the first step of a troubleshooting like this would be to localize the problem to at least a single device.  That is, you need to determine whether the problem is in the amplifier or the speaker before anything else can be done.  You should try your subwoofer with another amplifier or your amplifier with another subwoofer if possible.  Note that you can probably use a speaker that is not a subwoofer with your amplifier just to check if it's working as long as you restrict yourself to "quiet" levels.

A good (and easy) test to do on any speaker is check its resistance with a multimeter.  It should be roughly 4 or 8 ohms.  This number may be printed somewhere on the speaker, but you probably won't get such a precise value.  Anything in this ballpark, as in not "zero" or "infinite" (read as OL on many multimeters), is probably okay.

Answer (score 0):

Repairing electronics is an interesting and sadly disappearing art.  Everything I've learned about it I've learned from one blog: [Keith's Electronics Blog](http://www.neufeld.newton.ks.us/electronics/)

Apparently it's his job to fix electronics and he has decent writeups on everything he does.  From what I've read, 90% of the time it's the power supply - and he's written up power supply fixing.

I would read his blog for no other reason than it's interesting, but also it will probably give you an idea of what fixing your speakers will require and whether it's worth it.  Good luck.